# How to catch the error like : net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in ElectronJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

The status code will show me 404 when I write wrong adress.
But when I close the server, Electron give me an error dialog which is useless for me.
I need to catch this error to show uers 404 dialog.

[image]

There are my code:

```
const {
    net
} = require('electron').remote;
var cache = [];
var postData = querystring.stringify({
    'test': '1111'
});

const request = net.request({
    method: 'POST',
    protocol: 'http:',
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8080,
    path: '/TestCheck/TestMain',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
        'Content-Length': postData.length
    }
});

request.on('response', (response) => {
    // the error dialog appeared before this code executed.
    console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`);
    response.on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(`ERROR: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
    })
    response.on("data", (chunk) => {
        console.log("data：", chunk.toString());
    })
    response.on('end', () => {
        console.log("end");
    })
});
request.write(postData);
request.end();
```

Comment: `request.on("error", () => {...}` ?! But, display the user a 404 error message is useless when a connection error occur...

Comment: @Marc this function didn't work. 404 dialog is just an example, I want to tell users the net is not connected.

Comment: What module is the "net" variable ? The node net module has no "request" function. If its the http module then the code i posted works 1000%

Comment: The net module is a client-side API for issuing HTTP(S) requests in ElectronJS. I know where I was wrong. The `request.on("error,()=>{}")` should be the same level as the `request.on("response",()=>{})`. Thanks!

Comment: The client request instance should also emit a error event: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/client-request#event-error Did you put the `request.on("error"...` inside the "response" event ?

Comment: @Marc Yes,I did it. I confused the request event and the response event. That's why I'm worng  :)